# qemu-img convert rbd volumes between different ceph clusters accelerate

Tags: copy, qemu, volume, accelerate, librbd

Is there an elegant way to copy an RBD volume to another Ceph cluster?

I calculate the convert time with qemu-img 2.5 version or qemu-img 6.0 version, by copying a volume(capability is 2.5T and 18G only used) to another Ceph cluster.

```
qemu-img [2.5 or 6.0] convert -p -f raw rbd:pool_1/volume-orig_id:id=cinder:conf=1_ceph.conf:keyring=1_ceph.client.cinder.keyring -O raw rbd:pool_2/volume-new_id:id=cinder:conf=2_ceph.conf:keyring=2_ceph.client.cinder.keyring [-n -m 16 -W -S 4k]
```

Test `qemu-img convert` result:

qemu-img 2.5 spend **2 hours and 40 minutes** with no option parameter:

[image]

qemu-img 6.0 spend **3 hours and 3 minutes** with option parameter (*-m 16 -W -S 4k*):

[image]

Questions:

1, why 2.5 version write only used disk capability(18G), but 6.0 version write the hole disk 2.5T?

2, how to use qemu-img (2.5 or 6.0 version) accelerating convert RBD volume to another Ceph cluster or there is some other ways to approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main feature is `qemu-img convert -n` the `-n` option parameter.

If convert the disk with `'-n' skips the target volume creation (useful if the volume is created prior to running qemu-img)` parameter, it will write the hole disk capability to the destination rbd volume. Without it, the `qemu-img convert` only read the source volume used capability and write them to destination volume